# Javascript; variable function return,write to HTML

Tags: javascript

Having trouble with a javascript function writing to HTML id img tag. In the javascripts function "pageSetup" Im trying to write to the HTML "IMG" tag that contains a random pic.Bellow Ive listed the HTML code and the function that is attached to the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <link href="flowers.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="lab09.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = pageSetup();

            function pageSetup() {
                var nDate = new Date();
                var myBanner = displayBanner(nDate);
                alert(myBanner); /*This seems correct, returning a random
                                  picture 

                //document.getElementById(myBanner).src=
                var salesMessage = calcDaysToSale(nDate);
            }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <p>
            <img id="myBanner" src=" " alt="Carol's Flowers"/>
        </p>

function displayBanner(currentDate) {
    var imgsource;
    var month;
    month = currentDate.getMonth()+1;
    if ((month==12)|| (month==1) || (month==2)){
        imgsource ="winterLogo.gif";
    }
    else if ((month==3) || (month==4) || (month==5)) {
        imgsource ="springLogo.gif";
    }
    else if ((month==6) || (month==7) || (month==8)) {
        imgsource ="summerLogo.gif";
    }
    else if ((month==9) || (month==10) || (month==11)) {
        imgsource ="fallLogo.gif";
    }
    else {
        imgsource = "defaultLogo.gif";
    }
    alert( imgsource );
    return imgsource;
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem, exactly?

Comment: you're passing the image source to getElementById()?

Comment: You should avoid `window.onload = ...`, instead use `window.addEventListner('DOMContentLoaded', ...)`.

Comment: Also, your `displayBanner` function should be inside a `<script>` tag. Can't tell if you actually have it like this or this is just how you pasted the code here.

Comment: @Dai Im trying to display a random image that is selected from the function displayBanner. The function is returning an image. I think im having trouble with placing the image to the HTML <img> tag. The javascript code that is trying to write to the HTML <img> tag is  document.getElementById('myBanner').src=myBanner;

Answer (score 3):

You're passing the image source to getElementById(). Shouldn't you be passing 'myBanner'? As in `getElementById('myBanner').src = myBanner`?

Here's a working example using your code:

```js
function displayBanner(currentDate) {
    var imgsource;
    var month;
    month = currentDate.getMonth()+1;
    if ((month==12)|| (month==1) || (month==2)){
      imgsource ="http://placehold.it/200?text=winterLogo.gif";
    }
    else if ((month==3) || (month==4) || (month==5)) {
      imgsource ="http://placehold.it/200?text=springLogo.gif";
    }
    else if ((month==6) || (month==7) || (month==8)) {
      imgsource ="http://placehold.it/200?text=summerLogo.gif";
    }
    else if ((month==9) || (month==10) || (month==11)) {
      imgsource ="http://placehold.it/200?text=fallLogo.gif";
    }
    else {
      imgsource ="http://placehold.it/200?text=defaultLogo.gif";
    }
    alert( imgsource );
    return imgsource;
}

var src = displayBanner(new Date());
document.getElementById('myBanner').src = src;
```

```html
 <img id="myBanner" src=" " alt="Carol's Flowers"/>
```

Comment: I tried  document.getElementById('myBanner').src=myBanner; still not displaying the random image returned from the function to the HTML page.

Comment: @user001 Is `myBanner` the actual path to the image, or just the name of the image? You need the actual path.

Comment: Updated my answer with a working code example.

Comment: The function is returning the filename of the picture example: fallLogo.gif  , validated by alert(myBanner); ...its not untill I try to set the inmage in HTML is where the problem is by using the command in the javascript document.getElementById('myBanner').src=myBanner;

Comment: So what's your question? The example code works. So maybe your images aren't there? Are they in a subfolder?

Comment: @user001 When I go to my webpage its not displaying the image in the myBanner variable. Trying to place it in the <img id="myBanner" src=" " alt="Carol's Flowers"/> code where src="myBanner " . myBanner is the variable that is holding the returned pic named "fallLogo.gif" but the HTML isnt displaying the image.   -the "fallLogo.gif is in the same folder.-It works when I place the pic name directly into the src=" " in the HTML example:<img id="myBanner" src=" " alt="Carol's Flowers"/> code where src="fallLogo.gif "

Comment: Do you see errors in the console? Have you checked to ensure that your `getElementById` call is returning the `<img>`? Can you put your code up somewhere so I can see?